# Rotating a 4x4 Matrix Causes Scaling Over Time

Tags: c++, opengl, matrix, rotation, scenegraph

I am using `glm::rotate` to rotate a transformation matrix for a cube in a scene.

`"cube->t = glm::rotate(cube->t, stepTime * 50.f, glm::vec3(0.f, 1.f, 0.f));"` is called once per frame, where `cube->t` is the matrix in question.

The strange thing is that over the course of 20 minutes (or two minutes if I rotate by `stepTime * 5000.f` instead of `stepTime * 50.f`), the cube scales noticeably on the X and Z axes, where the scaling on those two axes is the same at all times (the height of the cube never changes, but the width and depth change by exactly the same amount). In the case of `5000.f`, becoming smaller, and with the normal `50.f` or `100.f`, becoming larger.

I thought this might be a question of rounding error, but other than that I have no idea what could be causing it. Is this rounding error? Can I solve it by normalizing the matrix on a regular basis? Does glm have a function for normalizing matrices, or do I have to write one myself?

Comment: You ask an interesting question, exposing the practical difference between mathematical analysis and iterative numerical results.  I suspect that you are right to normalize the matrix.

Comment: Sounds like rounding error, but I've not touched OpenGL for yonks - normalising the matrix sounds like an idea. Have you tried changing your rotation params to see if it affects it differently with different rotation vectors?

Comment: I haven't tried with different vectors. I'll tell you what happens once I've tested it.

Comment: Yes, it seems to scale only on the X and Y axes when I rotate the cube on its Z axis. So it reacts the same

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If it is an incremental, cumulative, loss of precision: instead of in-place updating the cube, keep an original un-rotated cube and keep track of the total rotational angle. Then on each step create a cube from the original un-rotated cube, transformed by the total accumulated rotational angle. In this way your cube will not suffer from cumulative rounding problems.

**Edit: In response to discussion with Miles, a more appropriate answer:**

If you can separate the rotational and translation components of the transformation matrix, and the problem is primarily with the accumulation of rotation introducing shear or scaling, you can rectify the problem by extracting the angle from the rotational component and re-creating the rotation matrix with that angle but unit length.

Comment: I'd like to use matrices for a videogame, where changes must be stored incrementally. How do I prevent my models from being scaled over time?

Comment: @MilesRufat-Latre. If they must be stored incrementally, they must be stored incrementally. However if you are seeing cumulative precision issues, the best (most stable/justifiable/robust) solution is to keep the original and some datastructure representing the cumulative transform to be applied. Are you sure this isn't possible in your case? Otherwise you can try normalisation. Are you applying translations as well as rotations?

Comment: Yes, I will be using both translations and rotations in the same matrices. (and I cannot by any means avoid storing transformations incrementally: The game includes a lot of 3D physics simulation, keeping track of transformations any other way would limit functionality)

Comment: Do quaternions have the same issue with scaling on rotation? (I don't mind if the rotations are imprecise, as long as there's no scaling happening as a result)

Comment: @MilesRufat-Latre: If you can separate the translation from the rotation then I guess you can extract the rotational angle and then recreate a rotation matrix of unit length with that particular angle represented. Is this what you mean by normalising?

Comment: Actually, that sounds much better than what I'm doing right now. That wasn't what I meant, but it will work better. What I meant is taking the first three members of the diagonal and normalizing them as you would normalize a 3-vector, resulting in an un-scaled matrix. I don't know if these changes will be compatible with my current setup with the physics engine.

Comment: @Miles: I think it conforms more to the outcome I think you're wanting.

Comment: @Miles. Thanks. Let me know if I've represented our discussion adequately.

Comment: You don't have to separate those pieces of information if there's no intention on scaling the cube. All you need to do is to orthonormalize the rotational part of the matrix after each rotation step. (Google for Gram Schmidt orthonormalization)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is a rounding error. A reasonable solution is to store orientation as a single number and in every frame build the matrix from scratch.

Comment: See my comment on the above answer.